# Program behaves differently when user can debug

Tags: debugging, abap

We encountered an annoying heisenbug: A few users (not all) of an ABAP program complain about a problem we are unable to reproduce (the search help for contract accounts in transaction FKKORD1 wouldn't appear for them. The transaction was heavily customized by external contractors).

To find a solution for the problem we temporarily gave the users a permission role to allow debugging in the production system so we could debug the problem under their user account when it occured. But the moment we gave them the role, the problem stopped occuring. When we removed the role, the problem occured again.

**Question: What reason could there be that an ABAP program behaves differently when executed by someone with debugging rights?**

The role we added contains only one permission:

```
Object S_DEVELOP
    ACTVT = 03
    DEVCLASS = *
    OBJNAME = *
    OBJTYPE = DEBUG
    P_GROUP = *
```

We did a permission trace with transaction ST01 and didn't even found a check for that permission when the problem did or didn't occur.

Permanently giving debugging rights to normal users is not an option, because the compliance standards our organization has to follow don't allow that.

Comment: are you using the old or the new debugger?

Comment: @vlad-ardelean We are using the new one. But note that we didn't even switch on debugging. The problem disappeared just because the user had the rights to enable it.

Comment: Could you add that single permission to an entirely new role and double-check again? I've seen some idi^Wprogrammers hard-code checks to specific role names...

Answer (score 0):

If changing their security roles make the transaction work, I would concentrate there.

If there was an error message occurring where they could do an SU53, but you probably already tried that.

The only other thing I can think of would be an initialization problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem generating your roles. There are some housekeeping jobs for roles that should run nightly.

Some users might have more roles than a SAP can handle. Adding a role might cause a completely different set of roles to be available to such users.

A programmer might explicitly have written an authority check for debugging rights to do some things differently. You should find this with transaction SU53.